# Under iPhone SDK are you supposed to checkin project.pbxproj into source control?

Tags: iphone, svn, sdk, conflict, pbxproj

I have been using SCM for myself, but now I am working in team-of-two :)  It appears that we are having conflicts on project.pbxproj and I think it is because that file should not be put under source control.  Is that file for personalizing one's environment, or does it have vital settings for build, etc.?

I want to delete it from SVN.

Using XCode 4.x with SVN under TeamForge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep the .pbxproj file under version control. It basically contains the project's structure in Xcode; groups, references to files, build settings, etc. Personal settings are stored in xcuserdata.

It's quite common to have conflicts there, it's just an xml file though, so merging is relatively easy (though tedious).

Comment: And if you don't want the file to auto-merge, you can tell subversion not to merge it. On the command-line:

svn propset svn:mime-type application/octet-stream MyProject/project.pbxproj

Comment: @EricS - what does propset do??  as for the check-in of this file, my project is a total mess.  We have multiple folders for Groups.  I think the problem occurred when I was making physical folders for the groups and my colleague was just making Groups (logical folders) of the same name.   Arrgghhh .... merging is not relatively easy, it is near impossible with GUIDS in the XML nodes.  There is no way to decode the merge.  I am ready to start over.  Any recommended reading to make it right if I start over?  I never had these problems with Eclipse and Android.

Comment: propset in this case would just tell subversion to treat the file as binary rather than text. subversion won't auto-merge binary files. I prefer to merge my project files by hand because when subversion inserts ">>>>>" conflict markers into an XML project file everything goes to hell quickly.